# how to get which label was clicked if clicked on label in the canvas graph

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]I am trying to click at the corner of the polygon and then logging the label which I have clicked.
I am attaching an event listener on canvas clicked and then logging the coordinates but they are not exactly the same which they were while drawing so how to get the intersection point(that is label) on click.

My code so far

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  coordinates = [
    {
      x:10,
      y:10,
      label:'A'
    },
        {
      x:10,
      y:250,
      label:'B'
    },
        {
      x:250,
      y:250,
      label:'C'
    },
        {
      x:250,
      y:150,
      label:'D'
    },

        {
      x:400,
      y:150,
      label:'E'
    },

        {
      x:400,
      y:10,
      label:'F'
    }

  ]
  /** Template reference to the canvas element */
  @ViewChild('canvasEl') canvasRef: ElementRef;

  /** Canvas 2d context */
  private context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.setDummyRoofLayout();
  }

   setDummyRoofLayout() {
    let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext(
      '2d'
    );
    let ctx2: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext(
      '2d'
    );
    let label: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext(
      '2d'
    );

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#EE9723';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.fillStyle = '#EE9723';
    ctx2.arc(10, 10, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx2.fill();

    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(10, 250, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx2.fill();

    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(250, 250, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx2.fill();

    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(250, 150, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx2.fill();

    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(400, 150, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx2.fill();

    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(400, 10, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx2.fill();

    ctx.moveTo(10, 10);

    ctx.lineTo(10, 250);

    ctx.lineTo(250, 250);

    ctx.lineTo(250, 150);

    ctx.lineTo(400, 150);

    ctx.lineTo(400, 10);

    ctx.lineTo(10, 10);

    ctx.stroke();

    label.beginPath();
    label.moveTo(10, 10);
    label.fillStyle = 'white';
    label.textAlign = 'center';
    label.textBaseline = 'middle';
    label.font = '.75rem Arial';
    label.fillText('A', 10, 10);
    label.fillText('B', 10, 250);
    label.fillText('C', 250, 250);
    label.fillText('D', 250, 150);
    label.fillText('E', 400, 150);
    label.fillText('F', 400, 10);

    label.stroke();

    ctx.canvas.addEventListener(
      'click',
      this.onclick.bind(this)
    );
  }

  onclick(e){
    console.log(e);
      let xAxis = e.layerX ;
    let yAxis = e.layerY;

    this.coordinates.forEach(element=>{
      if(element.x+4 <xAxis && element.y+4>yAxis){
        alert('label A clicked');

      }
    })

  }




}][1]][1]
```

[online editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvas-example-idizdb?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of Math:

```
intersect(point, coord) {
     return Math.sqrt((point.x-coord.x) ** 2 + (point.y - coord.y) ** 2) < 10; //where 10 = your circle radius
}

onclick(e: MouseEvent){
    const pos = {
      x: e.layerX,
      y: e.layerY
    };

    this.coordinates.forEach(coord => {
      if (this.intersect(pos, coord)) {
        alert('clicked: ' + coord.label);
      }
    })
  }
```

<kbd>**Stack Blitz Demo**</kbd>

Comment: it is working fine.. can you please tell me which maths formula is this?

Comment: Euclidean distance

Comment: so the euclidean distance between both the coordinates is always going to be less than the radius of the circle?

Comment: @HumbleDolt, it's based on your click distance to the circle distance. Since it's only a radius of 10, we only care if the distance is < 10.